# java.lang.StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, android

I am sure that, this ques code must be asked in this site. But I am not able to search, This is basic ques, but I am not getting it because of my poor basic concept-

```
public class A {

A obj = new A();

public static void main(String arg[])
{
    A ob = new A();
}
}
```

It is giving `java.lang.StackOverflowError`,Why?

Comment: What happens when a `new A` gets created?

Comment: calling constructor again and again

Comment: new Instance of class A created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class is essentially equivalent to:

```
public class A {

    A obj;
    public A() {
        obj = new A();
    }  

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        A ob = new A();
    }
}
```

Now you see how you got that error? Everytime you create an instance of `A`, the constructor get's called, which again invokes itself to create another instance, and this goes on filling up the stack till it overflows.

Answer (score 5):

Every time you create an object `A` it will create another object `A` that will create another object `A`...

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow errors occur because there is a very deep recursion within the application. When you instantiate `A`, you also call the same constructor to create another instance of `A` and hence, you have a recursive tree and thus causing the stack overflow error.

Hence, the real problem is deep recursive calls to instantiate `A`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create object of type A, you're creating new object of type A, which creates new object of type A etc.